# Unwanted Top White Space [Mobile View]

Tags: html, css

Hello so recently I've been building my personal website and been having troubles with my mobile view of my website.

**The Problem :** On a mobile device there is Unwanted White Space On Top Of Page (In nav Area). It basically covers the navbar.

**Solutions :** I've tried manipulating code, and seeing what could be causing this but no solution. Also used DevTools on google and it seems as if it won't show the top white space but only on the phone?

**Nav HTML Code :**

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <nav>
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="src/assets/TWINLOGO.png" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></a></div>
            <div class="openMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:black;"></i></div>
            <ul class="mainMenu">
                <!-- Center-aligned links -->
                <div class="nav-center">
                    <div class="navLogo"><a href="index.html"><img src="src/assets/TWINLOGO.png" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left-aligned links -->
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="leftLinks">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="leftLinks">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twins-merch-5.creator-spring.com/" target="_blank" class="leftLinks">Store</a></li>
                <div class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
                <!-- Right-aligned links -->
                <div class="nav-right">
                    <span class="icons">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/TwinPlayz_YT/?sub_confirmation=1" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yt.twinplayz" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/TwinPlayz_YT" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://discord.gg/6hmwuh5" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**Nav CSS Code :**

```
/* Nav BAR */
nav {
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height:fit-content;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}

/* Nav Main Menu */
nav .mainMenu {
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
}

/* Centered section inside the top navigation */
.nav-center{
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Right-aligned section inside the top navigation */
.nav-right {
    position:absolute;
    float: right;
    right:-100px;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

nav .mainMenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    margin:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 110, 255);
}

nav .openMenu {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 20px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .mainMenu .closeMenu , .icons i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .logo {
    margin: 6px;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}

.icons i {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    color:black;
}
```

**Website** - https://github.com/ConstantineLinardakis/TwinPlayzOfficial https://constantinelinardakis.github.io/TwinPlayzOfficial/index.html

**Any idea why this is happening? Could It be because of the Nav?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has to do with your body margin because the margin is set to 0 when I am inspecting your website. With that being said, perhaps your problem is due to using `height: fit-content;` I would suggest using a fixed height.

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 33.5vh; /* Change applied */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find at all what could be causing it? I just uploaded the fixed code to github and it still hasn't really done anything.... Im mainly confused why? This white space is only on the phone, and even if I try using devtools to see the white space it doesn't appear?

Comment: Could it be because of "min-height:100%" in body? @Kameron

Comment: @Kameron Please run the code snippets, provided with the question, in codepen or jsfiddle. Its clearly showing at the dev tools, that the body's margin (8px) is from the browser style sheet. OP has reset.css running at his life side, setting margin: 0;

Comment: @bitski though in my code and css, I have margin:0; already? How could this be happening still?

Comment: @Constantine Linardakis To prevent us from having misunderstandings, could you perhaps set up a codepen or the native SO equivalent? Your life site is fine margin wise because of that reset.css. The code provided with your question lacks that margin: 0 though

Comment: @ConstantineLinardakis try `padding-left: 0;` on your nav .mainMenu media query.

Comment: @ConstantineLinardakis actually I think I know what it is, do me a favor and comment out the `ul class mainMenu` and the inline styles and test that on the live mobile front-end and let me know if that white bar is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The [brower's style sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_styles) setting a margin to your `<body>` element by default is the culprit.

CSS fix removing browser styles default `<body>` margin (e.g.: 8px in Firefox):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```